# MongoDB - double $group make 2nd ObjectID a nested document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that after unwind has this structure (I've deleted information which I think is not relevant to the question)

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
        "Members" : {
                "City" : "New York"
        },
        "Group_name" : "Group A"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
        "Members" : {
                "City" : "Seattle"
        },
        "Group_name" : "Group A"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
        "Members" : {
                "City" : "Seattle"
        },
        "Group_name" : "Group A"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4"),
        "Members" : {
                "City" : "New York"
        },
        "Group_name" : "Group B"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5"),
        "Members" : {
                "City" : "Los Angeles"
        },
        "Group_name" : "Group B"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6"),
        "Members" : {
                "City" : "Los Angeles"
        },
        "Group_name" : "Group B"
}
```

I have used double Object Id to get a result like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "group" : "A", "city" : "New York" }, "totalMembers" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "group" : "A", "city" : "Seattle" }, "totalMembers" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "group" : "B", "city" : "New York" }, "totalMembers" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "group" : "B", "city" : "Los Angeles" }, "totalMembers" : 2 }
```

I want to be able to obtain a document with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "A",
    "Cities" : {
            "New York" : 1,
            "Seattle" : 2
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "B",
    "Cities" : {
            "New York" : 1,
            "Los Angeles" : 2
    }
}
```

This is my code so far, I haven't been able to group by 'group' and then by 'city'

```
db.Users_Group.aggregate([
{"$unwind":"$Members"},
{"$group":{"_id":{"group":"$Group_Name","City":"$Members.City"},"totalUsers":{"$sum":1}}},
{"$group":{"_id":"$_id.grupo","total":{"$sum":1}}}
] )
```

With this I get the sum of all members in that group not separated by cities.  How can I nest a document of the cities with the total of users of that city within each group?  Appreciate any help on this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run one more `$group` and prepare the data for [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) which takes an array of `k-v` pairs:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // your current aggregation stages
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.group",
            Cities: { $push: { k: "$_id.city", v: "$totalMembers" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            Cities: { $arrayToObject: "$Cities" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ySO5Xpe0DsQ)

Comment: I was close :D [https://mongoplayground.net/p/khZGY8lVD23](https://mongoplayground.net/p/khZGY8lVD23)

Comment: Thank you very much! This has been of so much help :)